# Проблемы transitions в Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Простой пример:
https://codepen.io/OneNice_/pen/yKOoJB

```css
div{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background:red;
 transition:1s all ease;
 }
 span{
 line-height:30px;
 transition:1s all ease;
 }
 div:hover{
  width:200px
 }
 div:hover span{
  line-height:60px;
 }
 div:hover div{
  width:100px
 }
 div div:hover{}
 div div{
 width:10px;
 background:orange;}
```

```html
<div>
 <span>123<br><div>321</div></span>
</div>
```

Есть  и два дочерних элемента span и div.
Для каждого элемента задано свойство transitions. И если в firefox при наведении мыши все анимации начнутся одновременно, то в хроме, в зависимости от кол-ва вложенных элементов,  воспроизведение анимации идёт почти поочерёдно.
На примере видно, что сначала увеличивается размер блоков и line-height на цифрах 123, и уже после, у вложенного блока div изменяется его line-height. Тоже самое происходит когда hover пропадает.

Я нашёл единственный подобный вопрос и ответом было просто убрать transitions у дочернего элемента, но это не решение...

Comment: Почему не подходит удаление transitions у дочернего элемента?

Comment: Тогда что делать, если одному или нескольким дочерним элементам он нужен, как и родителю? Ведь мы потеряем плавность. Даже в простом примере в посте, что нужно сделать, не трогая иерархию, чтобы всё работало 'по задумке', плавно.